# Big Rudin directly after baby rudin?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm a high school student who went through Rudin's Principles of Mathematical analysis a while ago in its entirety, except for the last two chapters.

I bought Real and Complex Analysis too, and although the preface says the first seven chapters of baby Rudin are sufficient preparation for the book, I know the book also includes graduate level complex analysis. 
As someone who doesn't have the faintest clue what complex analysis is about, should I read a book on undergrad complex analysis first?

Or will I be ok directly jumping to big rudin?

Again - Literally the only university level math textbook I've read is baby Rudin.

Thanks for the answers - I'll delete this question if its inappropriate.

Comment: It is probably in your interest to go through the usual non-analysis courses before doing any kind of graduate-level analysis. For instance: linear algebra and abstract algebra, possibly topology.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. As a followup related to the question, is that because I lack the necessary mathematical background to completely understand Rudin, or the mathematical maturity? I'll appreciate any answers.

Comment: If you can master baby Rudin, you can definitely try Real and complex analysis. Only half of the book deal with complex analysis so the lack of experience in complex analysis does not matter a lot.

Comment: I'd say that it's a matter of mathematical maturity; you should at least know all the "core" material of the undergrad experience at some point, and often different areas intersect and interact.

Comment: The standard term is ‘Papa Rudin’; source: Wikipedia article on Walter Rudin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Rudin

Comment: Go do it man. Barely any algebra required except maybe one proof using basic group theory and at one place it reveals relation between the change of measure of a set in same dimension after linear mapping and determinant of that map. You will appreciate this stuff if you read those last two chapters about Jacobian. Maybe those functional space etc. uses simple stuff involving linear map but definitions are given--entirely self contained.